# How to boost specific terms in elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

If I have the following mapping:

```
PUT /book
{
  "settings": {},
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "author": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can i boost specific authors higher than others?
In case of the below example:

```
PUT /book/_doc/1
{
  "title": "car parts",
   "author": "john smith"
}

PUT /book/_doc/2
{
  "title": "car",
   "author": "bob bobby"
}

PUT /book/_doc/3
{
  "title": "soap",
   "author": "sam sammy"
}

PUT /book/_doc/4
{
  "title": "car designs",
   "author": "joe walker"
}

GET /book/_search
{
   "query": {  
      "bool": {                    
        "should": [
             { "match": { "title": "car" }},
              { "match": { "title": "parts" }} 
         ]
       }
   }
}
```

How do I make it so my search will give me books by "joe walker" are at the top of the search results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to make use of `function_score`.

> The function_score allows you to modify the score of documents that are retrieved by a query.

[From here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html)

Base on your mappings try to run this query for example:

```
GET book/_search
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "match": {
                "title": "car"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "title": "parts"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "match": {
              "author": "joe walker"
            }
          },
          "weight": 30
        }
      ],
      "max_boost": 30,
      "score_mode": "max",
      "boost_mode": "multiply"
    }
  }
}
```

The `query` inside `function_score` is the same `should` query that you used.

Now we want to take all the results from the query and give more weight (increase the score) to `joe walker`'s books, meaning prioritize its books over the others.

To achieved that we created a function (inside `functions`) that compute a new score for each document returned by the query filtered by `joe walker` books.

You can play with the weight and other params.

Hope it helps

Comment: @i_have_question You're welcome and let me know if you have any question about this solution.

Comment: If my answer solved your issue, feel free to up-vote and/or accept the answer. thanks